# Sardinas-Patterson condition for unique decodability

Tags: information-theory

What is the condition of a code being uniquely decodable according to Sardinas-Patterson? I can't seem to find the condition anywhere, only the algorithm for checking if the code is uniquely decodable and some examples.

Comment: I'd say that the "condition" is simply that the algorithm says it's uniquely decodable.